# std::map operation by value or pointer?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I has a class A:

```
struct A
{
    std::map<int,int> aa;
}
```

and a class B:

```
struct B
{
    std::map<int,B> bb;
}
```

If those code in a infinite loop:

```
B b;
int inx=0;
while(true)
{
    A a;
    a.aa[0] = 0;
    b.bb[inx] = a;
    ++inx;
}
```

**Will that cause memory leak ?**
I want all values of `a` copy to `b[inx]`. I just want to know that is the implementaion of std::map pointer ?

Comment: By the way, you're using an `std::map<int, B>`, not `std::map<int, A>`. Besides that, neither `A` nor `B` implement `operator[]`. :-)

Comment: Please post a complete example that compiles - your code contains so many errors as I look it more

Comment: Sorry about dirty code, I'd fixed it up. :)
But the question is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will that cause memory leak ?

There are no memory leak in your program, but a compilation error, since there are no operator[] defined for struct B.

Assuming you add to map here:

```
while(true)
{
    A a;
    a[0] = 0;
    b[inx] = a;
    ++inx;
}
```

there are no memory leaks. The memory will increase until you use all int numbers, but that's normal, since they have to be stored somewhere in memory.